# how to I can show time with php code with Malaysia timezone

Tags: php

I need to show now time on my site in my city Batu Pahat/Malaysia
I'm using this code:

```
<?php echo date('H:i'); ?>
```

but it doesn't show the right time.
my country timezone : Kuala Lumpur/Malaysia 
my city time now is : 02:24 
 but on the site it shows me : 08:25
I don't know what time zone my server is in & I can't change that, please help me.

Comment: why have you added java tag?

Comment: The docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php tell you you can use `e` to get the TZ.

Comment: @RamonBoza or HTML, or localhost, or dreamweaver ...

Comment: To this questioner: if you find the solution is working fine for you, please accept the answer that shows they are helpful to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

```
<?php                        
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
    echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); //Returns IST
?>
```

Comment: I came across to this page while i was searching for the same solution. This code is working fine for me. Perhaps i could accept your answer behalf of this questioner. But, i would like to ask that, is there any solution to make the time format to 12-hour instead of 24-hour? Thanks Ashish!!

Comment: @Jornes Just `h` - For 12 Hours time instead using `H` - For 24 Hours time.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); 
    echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
?>
```

That should do the job, if you don't want it to show day-month-year remove the "d-m-y"

Answer (score 0):

I think its something like:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); //Timezone
```

Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('timezone');
```

Dunno which one you need, look up for it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php